# Beautifulsoup object does not contain full table from webpage, instead grabs first 100 rows

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape tables from the website spotrac.com and save the data to a pandas dataframe. **For whatever reason, if the table I am scraping is over 100 rows, the BeautifulSoup object only appears to grab the first 100 rows of the table.** If you run my code below, you'll see that the resulting dataframe has only 100 rows, and ends with "David Montgomery." If you visit the webpage (https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2019/base/running-back/) and ctrl+F "David Montgomery", you'll see that there are additional rows. If you change the webpage in the get row of the code to "https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2019/base/wide-receiver/" you'll see that the same thing happens. Only the first 100 rows are included in the BeautifulSoup object and in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Begin requests session
with requests.session() as s:
        # Get page
        r = s.get('https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2019/base/running-back/')
            
        # Get page content, find first table, and save to df
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
        table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
        df_list = pd.read_html(str(table))
        df = df_list[0]
```

I have read that changing the parser can help. I have tried using different parsers by replacing the BeautifulSoup object code with the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
```

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
```

Neither of these changes worked. I have run "pip install html5lib" and "pip install lxml" and confirmed that both were already installed.

Comment: I think it's probably because some of the entries are dynamically loaded using JavaScript. For that you would need a different package, such as `dryscrape` mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python

Comment: when I turn off JavaScript then this page display only 100 rows. `requests` and `Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScritp and you can't get more rows. You will have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you can try to use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome to get url used by JavaScript to get more rows and then you can use this url with `requests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to load extra data.

In `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` you can see it sends `POST` request with extra information `{'ajax': True, 'mobile': False}`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as s:
    
    r = s.post('https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2019/base/running-back/', data={'ajax': True, 'mobile': False})
        
    # Get page content, find first table, and save to df
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    df_list = pd.read_html(str(table))
    df = df_list[0]
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use request-html

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Begin requests session
    s = HTMLSession()
    # Get page
    r = s.get('https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2019/base/running-back/')
    r.html.render()
    # Get page content, find first table, and save to df
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    df_list = pd.read_html(str(table))
    df = df_list[0]
```

Then you will get 140 lines.